# Installation of amd 12.8 drivers failing, Why?

Tags: installation, ati, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

I recently downloaded the latest version of the amd raedon driver 12.8 from this link:-

[Driver_12.8](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

for my brand new 12.04 install with a default kernel version 3.2.0-29 and has followed the [link](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/08/install-amd-catalyst-128-on-ubuntu.html):-

to install the graphics driver but

I have tried several times, i get no error while installation but in the end when i run amdcccle i get this :-

[image]

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: i have already followed the instructions; they are pretty outdated.

Comment: here is the wiki link :- http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide for 12.8 and it's failing.

Comment: At what point of the Installation it's failing? there's a screenshot, but the font is small to be readable.